# Banner Ad with iPhone X? [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, iphone-x

So recently I integrated StartApp ads into my game. I am using `Swift` and `SpriteKit`. I ran my app on the `iPhone X` `simulator`, and found that the banner ad gets "cut off" by the "home" button on the `iPhone X`. I really don't know how to fix this. Anyone have ideas?

Here is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8fuv.jpg

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Xcode - Editor - Size to fit

[image]

Comment: I am using SpriteKit, as said in my question above. I'm not sure this will work.